# how to get result of php file in javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, html, textarea

I want to append the myadd.php file result to textarea. Code is as shown below:

```
<textarea name="_to" spellcheck="false" id="_to" cols="70" rows="1" tabindex="2" autocomplete="off"></textarea>
<button type="submit" form="SubmitForm" onclick="loadSubmitResults('_to');">Submit</button>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var urn='wdr';
function loadSubmitResults(to) {
var obj=document.getElementById(to);
var att = $().load('myadd.php?h='+urn);
obj.value+=att;
}
</script>
```

How does I should append the result of myadd.php file after typing some text in textarea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function loadSubmitResults(to) {
    var el = document.getElementById(to);
    $.get('myadd.php', { h: urn }, function(result){
        el.value += result;
    });
}
```

and change this:

```
onclick="loadSubmitResults('_to'); return false;"
```

Comment: Tell me what you need

Comment: I had execute one php file, but sometimes, the result is submitted & sometimes not. I don't know what to do. How is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean result is submitted? Request is not sent to server? or server error occurs and returns status 500? Check network and console tabs for errors, in chrome developer tools (press F12).